# Understanding backbone.geppetto

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, robotlegs, backbone.geppetto

Some questions about [backbone.gepetto](https://github.com/ModelN/backbone.geppetto) plugin

1. I have a layout and some view inside. How to pass view generated event to layout ? Instance view in layout:onRender, pass parentContext to view, and use this.context.dispatchToParent to send message to layout or listen view.context events in layout ? What strategy is better: parent listens child or child sends event to parent (says, render me) ?
2. In geppetto examples I saw only one context per one view,  but not  a one context to many views, how to share  code and data between widgets?
3. When to use dispatch, dispatchToParent, dispatchGlobally ?
4. What is main idea of context ? Without context, widget can listen events, can send them to parent or parent can listen them like context, what difference ?
5. How to determine what logic should be in the context and what in the view item ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Geppetto author, here.  I've responded to this question in the GitHub repo issues list.  See here: https://github.com/ModelN/backbone.geppetto/issues/5#issuecomment-11155226